# Why can't Open MPI configure find pmi2.h library?

Tags: configure, openmpi, slurm

Hi I am trying to compile Open MPI 1.10 with `pmi2.h` so that I can use it with `srun` command according to instructions here https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=slurm

This is my configure command

```
[avinash@baribu openmpi-1.10.0]$ ./configure CC=gcc CXX=g++ FC=gfortran --prefix=/home/avinash/openmpi110 --with-slurm --with-sge --with-pmi=/usr/include/slurm
```

but I get the error message at the end

```
--- MCA component common:pmi (m4 configuration macro)
checking for MCA component common:pmi compile mode... dso
checking if user requested PMI support... yes
checking if PMI support can be built... no
configure: WARNING: PMI support requested (via --with-pmi) but neither pmi.h
configure: WARNING: nor pmi2.h were found under locations:
configure: WARNING:     /usr/include/slurm
configure: WARNING:     /usr/include/slurm/slurm
configure: WARNING: Specified path: /usr/include/slurm
configure: WARNING: OR neither libpmi nor libpmi2 were found under:
configure: WARNING:     /usr/include/slurm/lib
configure: WARNING:     /usr/include/slurm/lib64
configure: WARNING: Specified path: 
configure: error: Aborting
```

which is weird because I see a `pmi2.h` file in `/usr/include/slurm`

```
[avinash@baribu openmpi-1.10.0]$ ls /usr/include/slurm
pmi2.h  pmi.h  slurmdb.h  slurm_errno.h  slurm.h  smd_ns.h  spank.h
```

I will appreciate any help with the configuration. Thanks.

Comment: You should probably pay closer attention to the output. The error message is that either the header files OR the libraries were not found. I would rather bet on the latter being the case. The `--with-pmi=BASE` option specifies the base of the PMI interface installation is `BASE`, not the path to the include files. If you set that path to `BASE`, the header files should be in `BASE/include/` and the libraries should be in `BASE/lib[64]/`. In your case it should probably be `/usr` and therefore Open MPI would probably compile with `--with-pmi` alone or with `--with-pmi=/usr`.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to email the information requested under http://www.open-mpi.org/community/help/ to the Open MPI users mailing list.  The config.log file, in particular, will likely contain more information.